# format string for databinding, thousands separator and brackets without Currency sign

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, formatting

I want to databind a grid column in WPF so that the value looks like this for negative numbers

(1,234.00)

I can do `Binding="{Binding Path=ContractBTM.BasisAmount,StringFormat={}{0:0.00;(0.00)}}"` but that does not give me the separator.

I can do `StringFormat=N` but the negative values use the minus sign.

I tried using the `#,###` syntax but it doesn't like the comma in my binding string.

OK
I ended up going with StringFormat={}{0:#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)} and ignoring the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ContractBTM.BasisAmount, StringFormat={}{0:0.00;(0,000.00)}}" />
```

Comment: That works, turns out WPF is"just kidding" when it reports 4 errors based on that syntax.

Comment: That is an issue with the XAML editor in Visual Studio, sometimes it shows errors that are not valid.